# Breakpoint for every catch block Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have more than 300 try catch block in all project.

How can i set/put **breakpoint** for **all catch** in try catch Visual Studio for my all project (Class etc everything) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to search `"try {"` (click CTRL+F) and add a breakpoint !!
I know that is the stupide way :/